# "FATAL EXCEPTION: main" on success callback for camera in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am using cordova 3.6 and android 4.4 and i used a simple example for opening a camera or choose picture from gallery but on every success callback for camera getting below error

```
02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.CameraOptionApp/com.CameraOptionApp.CameraOptionApp}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=18, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/5027 }} to activity {com.CameraOptionApp/com.CameraOptionApp.CameraOptionApp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2216)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=18, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/5027 }} to activity {com.CameraOptionApp/com.CameraOptionApp.CameraOptionApp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3302)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2715)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  ... 12 more
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onActivityResult(CordovaActivity.java:779)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5204)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3298)
    02-03 16:39:04.279: E/AndroidRuntime(3403):  ... 13 more
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403): Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException in Logger.java:438 :: Uncaught Exception
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.CameraOptionApp/com.CameraOptionApp.CameraOptionApp}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=18, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/5027 }} to activity {com.CameraOptionApp/com.CameraOptionApp.CameraOptionApp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2216)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=18, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/5027 }} to activity {com.CameraOptionApp/com.CameraOptionApp.CameraOptionApp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3302)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2715)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  ... 12 more
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onActivityResult(CordovaActivity.java:779)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5204)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3298)
    02-03 16:39:04.287: E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(3403):  ... 13 more
    02-03 16:39:04.291: D/wl(3403): WL.doPrepareAssetsWork in WL.java:287 :: no need to check web resource integrity
```

I tried on different machine also but having same issue.

Comment: can you put up your code here ?

Comment: I upgraded my cordova version 3.6 to 3.7.
My issue is fixed now.